# How To Prevent expanding JQuery BlockUI Dialog

Tags: jquery

how do i prevent expanding the jquery blockui dialog box? i thought draggable: false? but that does not work.

```
// this is essentially the default dialog if not overriden
    initDialog: function(e) {
        // modify timeout to do jquery dialog
        if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
            var _session = this;
            $("#" + this._clientId).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                bgiframe: true, draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        CallServer();
                            }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have misread your question, but is [`resizable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-resizable) what you're after?

```
resizable: false,
```

Comment: there you go... i know that there is property but didn't remember which one. - thanks :)